# Drupal : How to add javascript function on click event of a cck check box?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

I have added two fields one is check box and another one is text box to a content type and now i want to toggle the text box on clicking check box .Can any one help in doing so.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out the answer, we need to add in a conditional field setting (feature build in with drupal) amongst the two field to make them dependent on each other.